# How can I use a updated list in other if-else block?

Tags: java, if-statement, visibility

I am a beginner and working with IntelijIDEA configurations first time.
Conditions of a task is:

1. When starting the program with the -c parameter, the program should add a person with the given parameters to the end of the allPeople list, and display the id (index) on the screen.
2. When starting the program with the -r parameter, the program should display data about a person with the given id according to the format specified in the task.

The current code:

```
public class Solution{

    public static List<Person> allPeople = new ArrayList<Person>();

    static
    {
        allPeople.add(Person.createMale("Иванов Иван", new Date()));  //сегодня родился    id=0
        allPeople.add(Person.createMale("Петров Петр", new Date()));  //сегодня родился    id=1
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
    {
        if (Objects.equals(args[0], "-c"))
        {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date date = sdf.parse(args[3]);
            Person artman = Person.createMale(args[1], date);
            allPeople.add(artman);
            //trying to create a new list for updated allPeople list
            //List<Person> allPeopleUpd = new ArrayList<Person>(allPeople);
        }
        if (Objects.equals(args[0], "-r"))
        {
            List<Person> allPeopleUpd = new ArrayList<Person>(allPeople); //it's not an updated list
            String name = allPeopleUpd.get(Integer.parseInt(args[1])).getName();
            String sex = String.valueOf(allPeopleUpd.get(Integer.parseInt(args[1])).getSex());
            String bd = String.valueOf(allPeopleUpd.get(Integer.parseInt(args[1])).getBirthDate());
            System.out.println(name + " " + sex + " " + bd);
        }
    }
}
```

How to do a first condition I understood, but the problem is that the **second** if statement (with a "-r" parameter) don't see a changes that I made in the **first** if statement. What should I do to make a updated list visible for the **second** if statement?

P.S. createMale() and getters are from another Person class, never mind

Comment: so you mean when you call with both  `-c -r` ?

Comment: You will need to store the updated list to disk somewhere and then read it from disk.

Comment: Each time you start the program, it only executes what you have wrote, it doesn't know about the previous executions

Comment: @azro I mean call -c first to add a person into list and then call -r to print an information about him in console

Comment: @knittl the other problem is after call a -c and -r parameters in turn, after that I have a -u parameter to update an information and -d parameter to delete a person from the list (that's an condition of a task of my education program). So, reading a list from the disk every time, I think, not so usable method. But of course I could be wrong.

Comment: @TheRedBaron43 well, you can only start your program with a single parameter as first parameter. If you need to provide multiple values, you must start your program multiple times. If multiple invocations of your program need to work on the same data, you need to persist it somewhere (disk, database, …).

Comment: @knittl If I understood correctly I need to do next steps: in if statement with "-c" parameter add a person to list and then store it to the disk. And when I'll call if statements with another parameters (like "-r" or "-u") i need a read a list from disc, right?

Comment: I assume, yes. But I haven't written the task nor the requirements. The best option is to ask the author of the task what is asked exactly.

Comment: @knittl Okay, Thank you so much! I'll try to do like this. I'm only on the start of the road to become an java dev :)